# Can't Access UITextField in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I am trying to add a UITextField in a UIScrollView.  I cant get the UITextField in the UIScrollView, but clicking on the TextField does nothing.  I have tried numerous things.  The last thing I tried was making a custom ScrollView and checking the hitTest.  I set it to say "NO" on delaysContentTouches regardless and it still does nothing.  I set userInteractionEnabled on the TextField and still nothing.  I've looked on all the other similar questions and none of them have answers.

The code below show my attempt to add a Label and TextField to a UIView and then to add that UIView in the ScrollView.  It all works visually, but the TextField does nothing.

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 100, 30)];
lbl.text = @"Sample";
[lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[lbl setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

UITextField *txt = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115, 0, 195, 30)];
txt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
txt.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
//txt.placeholder = @"enter username";
txt.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
txt.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
txt.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
txt.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
[txt canBecomeFirstResponder];
txt.delegate=self;
txt.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;
[txt addTarget:self action:@selector(tfTouch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
txt.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;   

UIView *theView = [[UIView alloc] init];
theView.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;
[theView addSubview:lbl];
[theView addSubview:txt];
[scrollView addSubview:theView];
```

Comment: what do you want ???? do you want to add a text field on scrollview only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you have another view, you could add your textfield & label directly on the scrollview. Probably you just need to set a frame for your view. That should do it:

```
[theView sizeToFit];
```

Also set your contentSize correctly. `scrollView.contentSize = theView.bounds;`

Comment: My ultimate goal is to have a UIView with a Label and TextField dynamically repeated as many times as necessary.  I figured the best way to do this and keep them lined up was to put them in a UIView and then serial organize the UIViews vertically.

Comment: Are you saying that because the UIView is the right size, I am not able to touch the TextField even though I can see it?  (I'm not questioning you, just making sure I understand).

Comment: Yes. A view only gets touches within its bounds. If you turn on `theView.clipsToBounds`, you also won't see your other views anymore. ;)

Comment: Just now made it back to my puter.  The information you provided helped tremendously.  The thing that I was lacking was the init of the UIView.  Once I changed it to initWithFrame then everything worked.  Size to fit didn't work for some reason, but that was definitely the issue.  I made the UIView background red and got nothing.  I changed to initWithFrame and the background showed correctly and then the touch events started working again.  Thank you again jaydee3.